# Passing anonymous function to a method, storing it and executing it?

Tags: java, android

I need to pass a function to method, storing it on some variable visible inside the class, and lately executing it ( without parameters ).

In ActionScript 3 it would be :

```
private var lateCall : Function;
..

function getTheLateCall( o : Function ) : void
{
   lateCall = o;
}
...

function someFunction() : void
{
   lateCall();
}
```

- Is there something equal in Java ?

Comment: probably you need the delegation pattern [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No

You can though have alternates, one could be via `interface`

```
interface IFunc {
   void someFunction();
}
class Func1 implements IFunc
{
   void someFunction(){..}
}
class Func2 implements IFunc
{
   void someFunction(){..}
}
void getTheLateCall(IFunc func)
{
   func.someFunction();
}
```

So caller would instantiate specific `IFunc` implementation and pass it to `getTheLateCall`. But this is just one way of doing it..

Comment: @EvilDuck :) even I wonder, and I would make my +1 to you as no wonder! To me your answer is equally right.

Comment: Thank You. Pity that Java doesn't implementing such a great thing :|

Answer (score 6):

In Java you can't pass functions. What you can do though is create an interface with a method and make this interface a parameter of your function:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void method();
}

public void myFunction(MyInterface itf) {
   // store itf reference
}
```

Now you can create anonmymous interface implementation and pass it when calling myFunction:

```
myFunction(new MyInterface() {
    void method() {
        // Your code here
    }
});
```